# ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid Invalid column name when rendering xml and using :include method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml, activerecord

I'm using rails 2.3.4, rubygems 1.8.24, mac os x lion and ruby 1.9.3

I'm trying to render xml to an object called invoice. Now, i associated invoice with invoice_detail, so in my render :xml i wrote:

```
format.xml  { render :xml => @invoice.to_xml(:include => :invoice_detail) }
```

but an error occurs: ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid Invalid column name 'invoice_id'

i have no invoice_id column in my db, and now i want rails to understand that. I want it to look at the inventoryDocId column instead of looking for an invoice_id column that doesn't exist. How do i do that? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you created your model invoice_detail you have to specify the foreign key column :

```
class InvoiceDetail < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :invoice, :foreign_key => "inventoryDocId"
end
```

You have belongs_to options here : http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-belongs_to

Comment: Did you try to restart your server? What happens if you get an invoice_detail and you do raise invoice_detail.invoice.inspect

Comment: yes i did restart my server. but the same thing happens :( i'm sorry but i don't know how to raise invoice_detail.invoice.inspect. I'm a newbie. do i do that in the console?

Comment: in the console, you do : invoice_detail = InvoiceDetail.all.first and after invoice_detail.invoice, it will show you the invoice model detail.

Comment: i got it to work! thank you! now my problem is how to render xml using curl and come up with this kind of association. I'm gonna post another question. Thanks again!

Comment: So, what was your problem? Give your solution.

Comment: what i did was paste this line you gave me :foreign_key => "inventoryDocId"to the invoice model, following the has_many invoice_detail.